# Multiple projects using the same shared lib - duplicate symbol error

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, static-libraries, cocoapods

In my workspace I have the following sub projects:

- My App
- Common (Framework)
- Communication (Framework)

Using Cocoapods, both `Common` and `Communication` frameworks are using AFNetowrking lib.

After adding `Common` and `Communication` to `My App`, I receive the following error:

`duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation._responseSerializer in: ...`

How can this problem be solved?

Thanks

Comment: I would say remove `AFNetowrking` from both of the library and add it to My App. But there must a better way.

Comment: added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made it working. Attaching a [demo project](https://github.com/justme1/duplicateSymbolFix) that's working.

In short, in the Podfile, each project needs to include `pod AFNetworking`, and in `myApp` project choose the following in `Link Binary With Libraries`:

- libCommon.a
- libCommunication.a
- libPods-myApp-AFNetowrking.a

It took me few hours to make it work so hopefully you'll enjoy it as much as I have! :-)